# HP LaserJet P4014 PCL6 Network Printer - Print Queue Stalls

Tags: windows-7, printing, network-printer

I am connected to a HP LeserJet P4014 network printer in Windows 7. If I send multiple print jobs to the printer, say 3 single page prints from Word, the first page prints no problem at all but any subsiquent pages will sit in the queue for 10-15 mins before it prints, then the same gap until the next one etc.

After a page has printed it is still shown in the print queue during the wait for the next file to print - it is as if the printer is not getting a job finished message and after timing-out the next page will print.

Has anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't experienced the exact error but when we were setting up a sattelite network at a remote site we had no end of problems with the PCL drivers for both a HP P4015n and a HP 5550, they were printing out the first print job or the first page of a print job and then either: Idling with jobs in the print queue or displaying that the memory was full.
I never had it start to print after a time out though, it just stopped.
We solved these issues by using the PostScript drivers. I'm not sure if this is a viable solution for yourself but I would recommend giving it a go if it is possible.
If memory servers me correctly for the 4015 we had to use the Universal print drivers while the 5550 had its own PS drivers.

Hope it helps

Comment: Joe, thanks very much for the feedback, I'll take a look at the Postscript drivers.

Comment: Glad it could help. It certainally annoyed me when we were having the problem.